# What does it mean #!/conda_env/myenv/bin/Rscript in Rscript?

Tags: r

I am new to R script.
I found at the beginning of the R script,

```
#!/conda_env/myenv/bin/Rscript
library('httr')
```

May I know what does it mean `#!/conda_env/myenv/bin/Rscript`?
What happen if I do not add `#!/conda_env/myenv/bin/Rscript`?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol `#!` is known as a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

When a script starts with `#!/conda_env/myenv/bin/Rscript` you can run it from your terminal without specifying that it needs `Rscript`. If your file is called `myfile.R` you can run it with

```
/path/to/myfile.R
```

If you remove this line you have to run the file with the command

```
/conda_env/myenv/bin/Rscript /path/to/myfile.R
```

Edit: If `/path/to/myfile.R` cannot run you must make it executable. In your terminal this can be done with the command `chmod u+x myfile.R`.

Comment: Hello robertdj, when I define `#! /conda_env/myenv/bin/Rscript` at the beginning of "myfile.R", does it mean all the packages inside the myfile.R will use from the environment /conda_env/myenv?

Comment: If I want to import all the R library from the newly created environment (myenv_for_r) while python script will use another environment (myenv_for_py), how can I activate the myenv_for_r inside the R script? 

The flow is that  I will activate the myenv_for_py first and run the python script in which  R script will be run. But the R script will import all the packages from myenv_for_r environment.

Comment: R does not have environments like Python. I don't use R through conda, so I don't know how that works. These questions aren't really related to your OP, but seem more related to R packages, so consider asking a new question. 
Please upvote and/or accept the answer if it answered your question.

Comment: Perhaps add a note about executable bit?

Comment: @margusl Good point, I'll do that.